# Devexpress (10.2) GridControl isn't letting null value in column

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, devexpress

I am using VB.net within Visual Studio 2008. I currently have GridControl where one of the columns fetches a real number from the database. Whenever I try to remove the value I get a red 'X' saying that the input string is not the right format even though I know it can display null because the row underneath fetched a null value for that column. See picture below.

[image]

I tried to solve this by setting the ColumnEdit of the column to a textedit and then setting it's allowNullInput to True. Still same problem

Comment: Are you positive that the value is actually null then? Because as you state it can do it in the column below.

Comment: @Msarchet. I just added, within cellvaluechanging, setting the value to nothing. Same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the `ParseEditValue` event of the grid column.

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository

Public Class Form1
  Public WithEvents Edit As RepositoryItemTextEdit

  Public Sub Form1()
      Edit = GridView1.Columns("myColumn").ColumnEdit
  End Sub

  Private Sub Edit_ParseEditValue(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ConvertEditValueEventArgs) Handles Edit.ParseEditValue
    If IsNothing(e.Value) Or (Not (e.Value Is Nothing) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString)) Then
        e.Value = DBNull.Value
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you know some way to do this in VB.Net. My GridView.Columns["fieldName"].ColumnEdit doesn't contain ParseEditValue and I don't see this event in the properties.

Comment: @Kyra - Try the above conversion to VB.Net.  I am a rookie with VB.Net, so apologies in advance!

Comment: Thanks! :D Worked great. Only thing is your IF statement should be: `If IsNothing(e.Value) Or (Not (e.Value Is Nothing) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString)) Then` because you can't use '=' or '<>' to compare with nothing. Thanks so much :D